# How can I fix this error (Flutter Xcode IOS)

Tags: ios, flutter

> Command exited with non-zero exit-code: 65

> Run command: 'xcodebuild archive -workspace /Volumes/workspace/repository/ios/Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -destination generic/platform=iOS -archivePath /Volumes/workspace/build.xcarchive -derivedDataPath /Volumes/workspace/DerivedData -resultBundleVersion 3 -resultBundlePath /Volumes/workspace/resultbundle.xcresult -resultStreamPath /Volumes/workspace/tmp/resultBundleStream0faee827-d377-45e6-9136-688a7e2066f4.json -IDEPostProgressNotifications=YES CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=- AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=YES CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Automatic DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=2G4C676AQU COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO -hideShellScriptEnvironment'

> Command exited with non-zero exit-code: 65

> Run command: 'xcodebuild archive -workspace /Volumes/workspace/repository/ios/Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -destination generic/platform=iOS -archivePath /Volumes/workspace/build.xcarchive -derivedDataPath /Volumes/workspace/DerivedData -resultBundleVersion 3 -resultBundlePath /Volumes/workspace/resultbundle.xcresult -resultStreamPath /Volumes/workspace/tmp/resultBundleStream0faee827-d377-45e6-9136-688a7e2066f4.json -IDEPostProgressNotifications=YES CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=- AD_HOC_CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=YES CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Automatic DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=2G4C676AQU COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO -hideShellScriptEnvironment'